# How to extract a substring from main string starting from valid uuid using lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a main string as below
"/tmp/xjtscpdownload/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"

From the main string i need to extract a substring starting from the uuid part

```
"/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"
```

I tried 
`string.match("/tmp/xjtscpdownload/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/", "/[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[`a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}/(.)*/(.)*/$"

But noluck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to obtain

`"/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"`

from

```
"/tmp/xjtscpdownload/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"
```

or let's say `7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0`,  `output`  and `9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657` as this is what your pattern attempt suggests. Otherwise leave out the parenthesis in the following solution.

You can use a pattern like this:

```
local text = "/tmp/xjtscpdownload/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"

print(text:match("/([%x%-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)"))
```

`"/([^/]+)/"` captures at least one non-slash-character between two slashs.

**On your attempt:**

You cannot give counts like `{4}` in a string pattern.

You have to escape `-` with `%` as it is a magic character.

`(.)` would only capture a single character.

Please read the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) to find out what you did wrong and how to use string patterns properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try also the code

```
s="/tmp/xjtscpdownload/7eb17cc6-b3c9-4ebd-945b-c0e0656a33f0/output/9999.317528060546245771146821638997525068657/"

print(s:match("/.-/.-(/.+)$"))
```

It skips the first two "fields" by using a non-greedy match.